# Can i use ApiControllers from a library project in my solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have in the same project two solutions, one with the a complete API and a second
one (a library) with my ApiControllers. Is there a simple way to use the ApiControllers from my library in my Web API project?

Comment: You can reference one project from the other if that's what you're asking...

Comment: Yes I already have that, but the WebAPI won't use the ApiControllers in that other project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in Web API you can use controllers from external assemblies by providing a custom `IAssembliesResolver`.

```
public class CustomAssemblyResolver : DefaultAssembliesResolver
{
    public override ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        var assemblies = base.GetAssemblies();
        var controllersAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\PATH_TO_MY_CONTROLLERS_ASSEMBLY");
        assemblies.Add(controllersAssembly);

        return assemblies;
    }
}
```

or if you don't want to load DLL by hand

```
public class CustomAssemblyResolver : DefaultAssembliesResolver
{
    public override ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        var assemblies = base.GetAssemblies();
        var controllersAssembly = typeof(SomeTypeFromControllersLibrary).Assembly;
        assemblies.Add(controllersAssembly);

        return assemblies;
    }
}
```

You then have to register it against your `HttpConfiguration`:

> httpConfiguration.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new
>   CustomAssemblyResolver());

More info:
http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/using-controllers-from-an-external-assembly-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I'd found that too, but i don't have a dll that i use. I use a reference to my other project, so I can't use that LoadFrom function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you

Comment: With this line: Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\PATH_TO_MY_CONTROLLERS_ASSEMBLY"); are you reflecting a dll. I don't have a dll, i added a reference to my other solution project (the library). In that library I have my ApiControllers, I want to use those controllers.